# Talend - Read xml schema of Ldap from an xml file

Tags: ldap, talend

What I'm looking ?

- I want to read the schema of an `LDAPinput` from an xml file.

Info:

- The user will define the attributes that he wants in the xml file.
- The job will retrive only those attributes that are defined in the xml from the LDAP folder. How can I do that?

I am new to talend and I cant find any question on this in SO.

Comment: Do you mean you only want certain "columns" from your LDAP schema such as name and registration_date or criteria such as (name=syd)&(registration_date=2010-06-29)? Also, why do you want to use XML to define what data you want back?

Comment: yes that what i want. This is to let the user decide what column they want.

Comment: It was an either/or :) So you want to be able to filter rows and columns? Could you provide an example XML input/any input really that defines how you want to specify the columns and row filters?

Comment: sorry. didnt read it completely :). The xml file will only have column names such as name and date. It wont have criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, this is very painful to do properly and I'd seriously reconsider why you need to limit the columns back from the LDAP service and not just ignore the extraneous columns.

First of all you need to parse your XML input to get the requested columns and drop that into a list and then lob that into the globalMap.

What you're going to have to do is read in the entire output with all the columns from a correctly configured tLDAPInput component but with the schema for the component set to have a single dynamic column.

From here you'll need to use a tJavaRow/tJavaFlex component to loop through the list of expected columns from your XML input and then retrieve each column's name from the dynamic column's metadata and if the column name matches the provided values from your XML input then to output the value into an output column.

The output schema for your tJavaRow/tJavaFlex will need to contain as many columns as you could possibly have return (so every LDAP column for your service) but then populate them as they are needed. Alternatively you could output another dynamic schema column which means you don't need fixed schema columns but you'd have to add a meta column (so a column inside the dynamic column) with each match of column names.